# Getting first unlocked row

Tags: java, mysql, innodb, polling

I have a backend that pools a database for jobs. To facilitate system speedup, I would like for multiple backends to poll the database for jobs.

Job table:
jobid,date,action,completed

I was told this should be done with row locking. The backends will do a `SELECT ... LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;` However, after some testing, the selects do not skip locked rows and will block until that row is unlocked.

If there a way to get the first unlocked row (with FOR UPDATE)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are marking the row in some way, to show that some backend job is handling it. If so, you could follow a procedure like this:

1. Select .... Where STATUS='OPEN' LIMIT 1
2. Update ... Set STATUS='RUNNING' Where Job-Key=? AND STATUS='OPEN'
3. if Update count <> 1 then some other poller got to it first, so loop back to the
   select